# Creating a Korean to English Dictionary

Tags: languages

What package would be best for creating a multilingual dictionary? The glossaries package doesn't seem to work very well with Korean.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/8528) might be a good model to (try to) emulate. (Make sure you scroll down to see the images!)

Answer (score 1):

While initially interested in how to use parallel.sty, allowing me to set German and Latin side-by-side, I became aware of this [site](https://brannerchinese.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/parallel-text-and-vocabulary-in-latex/) providing code and compiled example.

Contrasting with my aim (as both writings may be set with Latin fonts), David Brenner showcases how to deal with different encodings, especially with xeCJK designed to assist with Chinese (the example) side-by-side with English. Yet Korean should work well, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can dissociate language support and packages which could offer you a layout suitable to your dictionary.

For the language side, you need to use `babel` or `polyglossia` with the proper option for your languages.

Then, for the layout side, it depends of what kind of dictionary you want. According to the layout needed, there are several packages which could fit (in particular, glossaries is one of the best). But you could also personalize the book class in order to obtain a special layout.